# iPhone how to create scrollable filter like Mashable App?

Tags: iphone

I'd like to create a scrollable filter just below the navigation bar like in the Mashable iPhone app.

Here's what it looks like:

http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/mashable/id356202138?mt=8

http://img20.imageshack.us/i/mashable.png/

Does anyone know how to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

That's certainly a custom UIView added as subView to their UITableView...

Comment: hi Macmade, is it UIViewScroll or just UIView?

Answer (score 0):

Yes this can be done by adding a number of buttons in a UIScrollView by a loop and then add two custom buttons (one for left arrow and one for right arrow) over your scrollView.

or

you can follow the tutorial

http://blog.sallarp.com/iphone-sliding-menu/

Comment: hi saadnib, thank you for this. How do I add the shadowing and arrow on the left and right?

Comment: for this you have to add images to the left and right custom buttons which you have to add over this slide menu view.